# getting duplicate list inside output list(checkedCitiesList) while updating selected list(select or deselect lists or individual)

Tags: angular

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() public next: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  counties: any[];
  cities: any[];
  cityName: string;
  selectedAllCounties: any;
  checkedCitiesList: any = [];
  checkedCountiesList: any = [];
  activeState: string;
  selectedAllCities: any;
  isShow = true;

  constructor(private  Apiservice: Apiservice) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedAllCounties = false;
    this.selectedAllCities = false;
  }

  getAllCounties() {
    if (this.isShow === true) {
      this.isShow = false;
    } else {
      this.isShow = true;
      this.selectedAllCities = false;
      this.cities = this.selectedAllCities;
      this.selectedAllCounties = false;
      this.activeState = '';
    }
    this.samradApiservice.getAllCounties().subscribe(
      (counties) => {
        this.counties = counties;
      });

  }

  getAllCity(cityName: any[], name) {
    this.cityName = name;
    this.activeState = name;
    this.cities = cityName;
    this.selectedAllCounties = false;
  }

  isAllCountiesSelected(isTrue , cities) {
    this.cities = cities;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++) {
      this.cities[i].isSelectedCity = this.selectedAllCities = isTrue;
    }
    this.getCheckedCitiesList();
    this.getCheckedContieslist();
  }

  getCheckedContieslist() {
    this.checkedCountiesList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.counties.length; i++) {
      if (this.counties[i].isSelected) {
        this.checkedCountiesList.push(this.counties[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log('checked lan ' + this.checkedCountiesList);
    this.Apiservice.setValueOfSelectedContiesList(this.checkedCountiesList);
  }

  checkUncheckAllCities() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++) {
      this.cities[i].isSelectedCity = this.selectedAllCities;
    }
    this.getCheckedCitiesList();
  }

  isAllCitiesSelected() {
    this.selectedAllCities = this.cities.every(function(item: any) {
      return item.isSelectedCity === true;
    });
    this.getCheckedCitiesList();
  }

  getCheckedCitiesList() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++) {
      if (!this.cities[i].isSelectedCity){
        const index = this.checkedCitiesList.indexOf(this.cities[i]);
        this.checkedCitiesList.splice(index, 1);
      } else
      {
        this.checkedCitiesList.push(this.cities[i]);
        console.log('checked ' + this.checkedCitiesList);
      }
    }
    console.log('checked kommun list ' + this.checkedCitiesList);
    this.Apiservice.setValueOfSelectedCityList(this.checkedCitiesList );
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ng-button (afOnClick)="getAllCounties()">Conties
    <i _ngcontent-lvi-c7="" class="i-angle-right"></i>
  </ng-button>
</div>
<div class="container" *ngIf="counties" [hidden]="isShow">
  <div class="card"  style="border-right: 1px solid lightgray">
    <ng-card>
      <h2>Conties</h2>
      <hr>
      <ul class="flex-container" *ngFor="let county of counties; let i = index">
        <div class="flex-checkboxes">
          <ng-checkbox onchange="isAllCountiesSelected(county.isSelected, county['cities'])" [(ngModel)]="county.isSelected">
          </ng-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-nameList">
          <li [class.active]="county.name === activeState" (click)="getAllCity(county['cities'], county.name)">
            {{county.name}}
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow"> <i _ngcontent-lvi-c7=""  class="i-angle-right i-right-arrow"></i></div>
      </ul>
    </ng-card>
  </div>
  <div class="card"  style="border-right: 1px solid lightgray;margin-top: 4rem" *ngIf="cities">
    <ng-card >
      <h2>{{cityName}}</h2>
      <hr>
      <div style="margin-top: 15px">
        <ng-checkbox onchange="checkUncheckAllCities()" [(ngModel)]="selectedAllCities" ></ng-checkbox>
      </div>
      <ul class="flex-container" *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index">
        <div class="flex-checkboxes">
          <ng-checkbox (afOnChange)="isAllCitiesSelected()" [(ngModel)]="city.isSelectedCity">
          </ng-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-nameList">
          <li>
            {{city.name}}
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </ng-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me clear you one thing, i could not paste here orginal code, but made changes if there is spelling miskate I really sorry for that. I have main list like counties which all have checkboxes and when i click on any of counties checkbox the sublist(which is cities list) will popup with all element selected. I can select multiple list on counties and as well sublist which is cities list, it's multi selection list and sublists. Whole code is working very well , but problem is that when i checked multiple select counties and there under mutliple sublist which is cities list. I got problem here getCheckedCitiesList() , It give med duplicate list even if i want to delete some element in sublist(cities) I want the whole list not to be duplicate but just delete those element which i want to delete or if i update sublist, I got like this citiesList= name1, name2, name3, name4 remeber it's getting from multiple selected list, when i want to delete for example name2 and push again i get duplicate for example citiesList= name1, name2, name3, name4,name1,name3, name4, like this if i unchecked one more like name3,element from cities list than again citiesList= name1, name2, name3, name4,name1,name3, name4,name1, name4, mean i get duplicate list pushed in final list wherever i want to delete any element in cities list. I hope that i be able to explain the problem, any help appreciated

Comment: Any one have any idea plz?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() public next: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  counties: any[];
  cities: any[];
  cityName: string;
  selectedAllCounties: any;
  checkedCitiesList: any = [];
  checkedCountiesList: any = [];
  activeState: string;
  selectedAllCities: any;
  isShow = true;
  tempList: any[] = [];
  checked: any;

  constructor(private  Apiservice: Apiservice) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedAllCounties = false;
    this.selectedAllCities = false;
  }

  getAllCounties() {
    if (this.isShow === true) {
      this.isShow = false;
    } else {
      this.isShow = true;
      this.selectedAllCities = false;
      this.cities = this.selectedAllCities;
      this.selectedAllCounties = false;
      this.activeState = '';
    }
    this.samradApiservice.getAllCounties().subscribe(
      (counties) => {
        this.counties = counties;
      });

  }

  getAllCity(cityName: any[], name) {
    this.cityName = name;
    this.activeState = name;
    this.cities = cityName;
    this.selectedAllCounties = false;
  }

  isAllCountiesSelected(isTrue , cities) {
    this.cities = cities;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++) {
      this.cities[i].isSelectedCity = this.selectedAllCities = isTrue;
    }
    this.getCheckedCitiesList();
    this.getCheckedContieslist();
  }

  getCheckedContieslist() {
    this.checkedCountiesList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.counties.length; i++) {
      if (this.counties[i].isSelected) {
        this.checkedCountiesList.push(this.counties[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log('checked lan ' + this.checkedCountiesList);
    this.Apiservice.setValueOfSelectedContiesList(this.checkedCountiesList);
  }

  checkUncheckAllCities() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++) {
      this.cities[i].isSelectedCity = this.selectedAllCities;
    }
    this.getCheckedCitiesList();
  }

  isAllCitiesSelected(event, checked) {
  this.element = event;
  this.checked = checked;
    this.selectedAllCities = this.cities.every(function(item: any) {
      return item.isSelectedCity === true;
    });
    this.getCheckedCitiesList();
  }

  getCheckedCitiesList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++) {
      if (this.cities[i].isSelectedCity) {
        this.checkedCitiesList.push(this.cities[i]);
      }
    }
    if(this.element === false) {
      this.tempList = this.checkedCitiesList.filter(value => {
        return value.isSelectedCity !== this.element;
      });
    } else{
      this.tempList = this.checkedCitiesList.filter(value => {
        return value.isSelectedCity === true;
      });
    }
    console.log('checked list ' + this.tempList );
    this.Apiservice.setValueOfSelectedCityList(this.tempList);
  }

}
```

use this where you want to receive your apiservice new Set([...tempList] to avoid duplication thats all. Just change these lines inside this method getCheckedCitiesList() works all